# How to retrieve an image from fbprofilepictureview and store this image into database

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad

Display the profile pic.

```
      self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;
```

but

```
       for (NSObject *obj in [userProfileImage subviews]) {
        if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImageView *objImg = (UIImageView *)obj;
            img_ProfilePictureImg.image = objImg.image;
            break;
        }
    }
    img_ProfilePictureImg.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:profileImage];
```

i didn't get ---fbprofilepicture

```
     UIImage *img_Profile = --------.imageView.image; // How to get that image view 
     NSData *dataOfProfilePic = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img_Profile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/username/picture?redirect=true`

Using this url you can get profile pic.

In Facebook Delegate `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` you can get the image url of User Profile pic

```
 - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user 
{

NSString *imageUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?redirect=true", user.username];

}
```

Comment: Thanks.I got it. but i have one doubt. that is i have to store this image into my database.how to convert this string into nsdata.

Comment: You should store Image url in DB rather than image.

Comment: user.username returns null for me. Any idea why?

Comment: I managed to query the graph API using the user.id and it seems to work