# How Do You Find Someone's Facebook ProfileID?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am working on an iOS app that loads peoples' profile pictures into an instance of FBProfilePictureView, which has a property of profileID. Is there a way to easily find someone's profileID?

Comment: Where do you get the `people` from?

Comment: Just if I want to search anyone on Facebook and find that person's ID.

Comment: How should this work if the User is called "John Doe", meaning he has a common name? How will you find out which is the "right" one?

Comment: Well say I am on the correct John Doe's Facebook timeline. Then is there a way to find his ID?

Comment: Being on the Timeline doesn't help you if you build an app which need to pull this programmatically. You said you wanted to search for a user, already being on someone's profile is completely different.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to pull it programatically. For now I would like to create an array of userIDs of certain people I search for on Facebook as quickly as possible. The problem is finding their IDs. Some of the IDs are displayed in the URL but others aren't.

Comment: How should your search work? Inside the FB mobile app? If so, how exactly do you want to generate an array from the search results? I don't really understand how your iOS app should be able to do that without using the Graph API in any form.

Comment: So basically I have an instance of FBProfilePictureView in the storyboard of the app called profPicView. self.profPicView.profileID = @"georgebush" loads a picture of George Bush. All I want is to hard code an array of profileIDs of random people, so that I have many to choose from when I want to change the profPicView picture. But I want to find a way to find the profileID of a person who's profile I am currently viewing on Facebook.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/georgewbush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm conflicted as to whether this should be in the comments or an answer, but here's how:

You use the Open Graph API [found here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user)

A call of `http://graph.facebook.com/username` returns you a bunch of Json which you can get the `id` value from.

So, `http://graph.facebook.com/facebook` returns:

```
{
   "id": "20531316728",
   "about": "The Facebook Page celebrates how our friends inspire us, support us, and help us discover the world when we connect.",
   "can_post": false,
   "category": "Product/service",
   "checkins": 348,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10152513030211729",
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 62,
      "source": "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t31.0-8/q71/s720x720/1553497_10152513030211729_1664524928_o.jpg"
   },
   "founded": "February 4, 2004",
   "has_added_app": false,
   "is_community_page": false,
   "is_published": true,
   "likes": 152791404,
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/facebook",
   "mission": "Founded in 2004, Facebook\u2019s mission is to give people the power to share and make the world more open and connected. People use Facebook to stay connected with friends and family, to discover what\u2019s going on in the world, and to share and express what matters to them.",
   "name": "Facebook",
   "parking": {
      "lot": 0,
      "street": 0,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "talking_about_count": 2149385,
   "username": "facebook",
   "website": "http://www.facebook.com",
   "were_here_count": 0
}
```

Comment: I have tried this several times, and the IDs it gives me don't seem to be correct. The FBProfilePictureView doesn't load a picture when I update the corresponding ID.

Comment: Hm. facebook.com/20531316728 = facebook.com/facebook, and facebook.com/1360261785 = facebook.com/eric.lagergren.9 (me), and facebook.com/197707510271223 = facebook.com/stackexchange so the IDs it's giving *me* are correct...

Comment: It seems to be working for celebrity pages, but not for my friends (who don't have any privacy settings).

Comment: I'm baffled. Is it giving you any error messages? Because I just used my personal ID (which I listed in the previous comment) and it worked correctly.

Comment: Interesting, because your ID works fine when loading your Facebook page, but doesn't work when pulling your picture.

Comment: So basically I have an instance of FBProfilePictureView in the storyboard of the app called profPicView. self.profPicView.profileID = @"georgebush" loads a picture of George Bush.

Comment: self.profPicView.profileID = @"1360261758" // (your ID) doesn't load anything

Comment: But when I search https://graph.facebook.com/JimmyKimmelLive and input his ID into the profPicView.profileID property, it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20741279/2967113 other than that I'm all out of answers, sorry. Either I'm having a stupid moment or something, but I'm at a loss, especially without seeing the whole source. Sorry.

Comment: No problem! I'm pretty sure you're right, as it seems to be working for most public profiles. I'll let you know if I figure out what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: Please do, this is pretty intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [Facebook Tool](https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME) ? You can have ID and some other information (In JSon format) about people with only replacing their username in the URL.

Comment: I have tried this several times, and the IDs it gives me don't seem to be correct. The FBProfilePictureView doesn't load a picture when I update the corresponding ID.

Comment: It seems to be working for celebrity pages, but not for my friends (who don't have any privacy settings).